# two date format in same column in sql ,cant change that to standard date format (yy-mm-dd)

Tags: mysql

imported csv file to sql table ,there are two date format in date column one is: yy-mm-dd ,
second:dd-mm-year,need to update all date column to any one standard 
i tried

```
ALTER TABLE `0_temp_data_aug_sept_2017_1` ALTER COLUMN date AS (YYYY-MM-DD);
```

is not working got stuck here,need help....

thanks in advance..

i attached image below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried the query on my data first before writing the answer and it works PERFECTLY....!!(MySQL query as the tag is mysql).

update `table_name` set `column_name` = (DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%m/%d/%y'))

As seen in your table, WHERE condition can be used further to distinguish between columns having different formats, rest of my query will set ALL records into a SINGLE DATE_FORMAT as asked by you.you can change '%m/%d/%y' as '%d/%m/%y' or whatever u feel like !!

Please let me know if any other help is needed !!

Comment: column which as 2017-01-08 yy-mm-dd update well but format dd-mm-yy as updated empty

Comment: use where condition after my query to select columns having yy-mm-dd or whatever BASED ON A UNIQUE condition/identifier, if not , add a new column as a flag having values 0 or 1 and then use WHERE condition after my query .

Answer (score 0):

I propose using STR_TO_DATE function during import adding following

```
SET your_date_column = STR_TO_DATE(@date_var, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

(assuming your_date_column  is your date column in table and @date_var is variable read from csv file)